# Error to access property from a library

Tags: ios, objective-c, lib

I have a class that imports another one, and I'm trying to access a property of this class, but I'm getting an error telling me that the value has no member. What can I do?

The errors occur in self.cachedImageView

Class of the lib:

```
 #import "JSQPhotoMediaItem.h"


 @interface JSQPhotoMediaItem ()

 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *cachedImageView;

 @end


 @implementation JSQPhotoMediaItem
```

and the methods to implementation go on.

My Class trying to access cachedImageView

```
 override func mediaView() -> UIView? {

    if !self.hasFile {
        return nil
    }

    if self.cachedImageView == nil {
        let size = self.mediaViewDisplaySize()

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let lightGrayColor = UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGray()
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGray()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "file_placeholder")?.jsq_imageMasked(with: lightGrayColor.jsq_colorByDarkeningColor(withValue: 0.4))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center

        let RightMargin = CGFloat(10)
        let BottomMargin = CGFloat(20)

        self.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width / 2, height: 20)

        let point = CGPoint(x: 1.5 * imageView.center.x - RightMargin, y: imageView.frame.height - BottomMargin)
        self.label.center = imageView.convert(point, from: imageView.superview)
        self.label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
        self.label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14.0)
        imageView.addSubview(label)

        JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker.applyBubbleImageMask(toMediaView: imageView, isOutgoing: self.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing)

        self.cachedImageView = imageView
    }

    return self.cachedImageView
}
```

Comment: Did you declare `cachedImageView` as a property of your class? Is your class a subclass of `JSQPhotoMediaItem`?

Comment: I imported the class to my class

Comment: Did you simply import the framework or did you subclass the object? You are saying `self.` so you are trying to access the property of your class.  Simply importing a definition of some other class doesn't magically add properties to an unrelated class

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are making you property in .m file rather then .h file. The .m file in objective c is private. If you want to make something public and accessible outside the class, declare it in .h file. It will work for sure. If this works, don't forget to accept the answer please.